# Ideal code to populate form fields in php

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and looking for an ideal way to populate form fields.
I have a class (Cl.tasks) which has the required methods. A Tasks.php page which views the data. and a tasks.js that runs jquery code for other related tasks.

The form exists in tasks.php. So should i call the class in the field like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name" value="<?php $task= new task;  echo $task->listTaskDetail("accountname"); ?>" placeholder="Task Name">
```

or is there an more ideal way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: You don't want to instantiate a new task for every field, so you should create a new instance before you start outputting any HTML. By the time you go to output, you should ideally have all the data ready to go for output. For example - here you have no way of handling any errors that may arise from `new task;` etc

Comment: I got it to work using a third page (handler) that instantiate the class if #_POST. Is there a way to get the data returned inserted into the modal form automatically. The handler is from a  while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($myTasks)){...}

Answer (score 0):

```
##the better way would be ##
call your class before the form:

<?php
//get instant of class task.
$task=new task();
?>`enter code here`
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name" value="<?php echo $task->listTaskDetail("accountname"); ?>" placeholder="Task Name">
```